# First Semester Linear Algebra Course (Answers are more than welcome)

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics

I'm really struggling to understand what I supposed to do 
thank you

Show that the elementary row operation of row replacement preserves the solution set of the system. For notational convenience, you may assume the system is 3 × 3. Thus, show that if (s1,s2,s3) is a solution of the original system, then it is also a solution of the transformed system, and vice versa.
Hint: Let the original system be

a11x1 + a12x2 + a13x3 = b1

a21x1 + a22x2 + a23x3 = b2

a31x1 + a32x2 + a33x3 = b3

and assume that we multiply the second row by a scalar c and add it to the first row. That is, the transformed system is

a11x1 +a12x2 +a13x3 +c·(a21x1 +a22x2 +a23x3) = b1 +c·b2

a21x1 + a22x2 + a23x3 = b2

a31x1 + a32x2 + a33x3 = b3

First, assume that (s1, s2, s3) is a solution of the original system, and show that it is a solution of the transformed system. Then, assume that (s1,s2,s3) is a solution of the transformed system, and show that it is a solution of the original system.

Comment: What is the question? It should be more than "I don't understand, help please"

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Visit following link for MathJax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hi, welcome.  It is all spelled out for you right in the problem.  What's the first part that's confusing?